# differences between Lazy.ByteString and Lazy.Char8.ByteString

Tags: haskell

I am bit confused over the codes in [real world haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/read/code-case-study-parsing-a-binary-data-format.html)

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8 as L8
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as L

matchHeader :: L.ByteString -> L.ByteString -> Maybe L.ByteString
matchHeader prefix str
    | prefix `L8.isPrefixOf` str
        = Just (L8.dropWhile isSpace (L.drop (L.length prefix) str))
    | otherwise
        = Nothing
```

It seems `L` and `L8` can be used interchangeably somewhere in this function, compiles fine if I replace `L` with `L8` especially for the type `L.ByteString` and `L8.ByteString`, I saw in hackage, they're linked to the same source, does that mean `Data.ByteString.Lazy.Char8.ByteString` is the same as `Data.ByteString.Lazy.ByteString` ? Why `L8.isPrefixOf` is used here but not `L.isPrefixOf`?

Comment: I was originally a bit confused by this so I wrote a [tutorial on ByteString](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/tekul/bytestring-bits-and-pieces) on FPComplete which you might find useful. It's mainly about non-lazy bytestrings but the differences between the `Word8` and `Char` versions are the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's funny, I've used all the ByteStrings but never noticed (until you mentioned) it that the Char8 and Word8 versions are internally the same data type.

Once mentioned though, I had to go and look at the code....  The following line in Data/ByteString/Lazy/Char8.hs shows that not only are the data types the same, but many of the functions are reexported identically....

```
-- Functions transparently exported
import Data.ByteString.Lazy 
        (fromChunks, toChunks, fromStrict, toStrict
        ,empty,null,length,tail,init,append,reverse,transpose,cycle
        ,concat,take,drop,splitAt,intercalate,isPrefixOf,group,inits,tails,copy
        ,hGetContents, hGet, hPut, getContents
        ,hGetNonBlocking, hPutNonBlocking
        ,putStr, hPutStr, interact)
```

So it would seem that most of Data.ByteString.(Lazy.)?Char8 are just a convenience wrapper around Data.ByteString(.Lazy)?.  This also explains to me why `show` has always created stringy output for Word8 ByteStrings.

Of course some stuff does differ, as you can see when you try to create a ByteString-

```
B.pack "abcd"  -- This fails
B.pack [65, 66, 67, 68] -- output is "ABCD"
B8.pack "abcd"  -- This works
```

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/bytestring), both `Lazy.ByteString` and `Lazy.Char.ByteString` are a space-efficient representation of a `Word8` vector, supporting many efficient operations. So, internally they seem to be same and you can use them interchangeably.

But `Lazy.Char.ByteString` has additionally these characteristics:

- All Chars will be truncated to 8 bits (So be careful!)
- The Char8 interface to bytestrings provides an instance of `IsString` for the `ByteString` type, enabling you to use string literals, and have them implicitly packed to ByteStrings. (you should enable `OverloadedStrings` extension for this)